# Beamer color box doesn't extend to cover frame number

Tags: beamer, lyx, slideshow

My latex preamble for `beamer` in lyx:

```
\usetheme{Madrid}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=None}
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}
{
   \leavevmode%
   \hbox{%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth,ht=2.75ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
     \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~(\insertshortinstitute)
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2ex,dp=1ex,right]{framenumber}%
    \usebeamerfont{framenumber}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
     \end{beamercolorbox}}%
      \vskip0pt%
}
\usebeamertemplate{mytheme}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
```

The box color doesn't extend to the frame number (it appears black and white and half box is author).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the following is closer to the expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=None}
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}
{
   \leavevmode%
   \hbox{%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth,ht=2.75ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
     \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~(\insertshortinstitute)
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.75ex,dp=1ex,right]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{framenumber}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
     \end{beamercolorbox}}%
      \vskip0pt%
}
\usebeamertemplate{mytheme}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\title{title}
\author{Author name}
\institute{Institute}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frametitle}
contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.75ex,dp=1ex,right]{framenumber}` you are drawing a box with with the `framenumber` color. This colour normally does not exist. You could either define it to be whatever colour you like or you could use `\setbeamercolor{framenumber}{parent={author in head/foot}}` to make it the same as the colour of the left side of your footline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{framenumber}{parent={author in head/foot}}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=None}
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}
{
   \leavevmode%
   \hbox{%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth,ht=2.75ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
     \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~(\insertshortinstitute)
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.75ex,dp=1ex,right]{framenumber}%
    \usebeamerfont{framenumber}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
     \end{beamercolorbox}}%
      \vskip0pt%
}
\usebeamertemplate{mytheme}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```